# Cumulative Relative Performance - 'Mismatched input '|PE|' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'' error with Pine Script

Tags: for-loop, pine-script

I want to get a cummulative relative Performance Line.

I get this error message. I don't know what i am doing wrong. Im trying it now for some time now. Can you help me?

Error: "**Mismatched input '|PE|' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.**"

```
change = (close[1]-close[2])/close[2])

n = 252 
sum = 0 

sais(change, n) => for i=0 to n-1 
    sum := sum + change [n] 

plot(sais, color=color.blue)
```

Answer (score 0):

The weird error is most likely caused by the fact that you use both the single-line and the multi-line function declaration syntax. It has to be multiline because of the `for` cycle, so the first line after `=>` should be empty, and the code should start on the next line, indented. This is how your function should look (formatting-wise):

```
sais(change, n) => 
    for i=0 to n-1 
        sum := sum + change [n]
```

Note that this won't work either because the function cannot modify a global variable `sum`. You'd need to create a local variable inside the scope of the function to store the value and then return it and assign it to your global `sum`. Depending on what you want to achieve, it might look something like this:

```
<...>
sum = 0 

sais(change, n) =>
    local_sum = 0
    for i=0 to n-1 
        local_sum := local_sum + change[n] 
    local_sum
    
sum := sais(change, n)
```